# Rubyの正規表現で、特定の文字列を含まれる毎に配列に格納したい。

Tags: ruby, 正規表現

Ruby の正規表現で、String の文字列中に特定の文字列（例では母音[aiueo]）が含まれる毎に配列に格納するという判定をしたいです。どのように記述すればよいでしょうか。
以下に入力・出力例を記載します。

```
"sayounara"
> ["sa","yo","u","na","ra"]
```

Answer (score 3):

文字列に[`scan` メソッド](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.5.0/class/String.html#I_SCAN)があります。

```
result = "sayounara".scan /[^aeiou]*[aeiou]/
# => ["sa", "yo", "u", "na", "ra"]
```

Comment: 早速ありがとうございます！成功しました